# Count Number of Visits from Each Client

Tags: java, html

I am having a bit of troubles trying to get this to work. The idea is that every time the page is refreshed it counts upward. I think it has to do with the immutable object, but I would like to use one to get experience with immutable/mutable objects.

The problem is that it only counts once, then it stops counting upward... I cant seem to figure out what it is exactly that is causing this to fail...

(I am using NetBeans to develop this, hence any strange comments)

Source:

```
/*
 * To change this license header, choose License Headers in Project Properties.
 * To change this template file, choose Tools | Templates
 * and open the template in the editor.
 */

package Question1;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.PrintWriter;
import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.annotation.WebServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpSession;

/**
 *
 * @author Owner
 */
@WebServlet(name = "EX02W03", urlPatterns = {"/EX02W03"})
public class Q1Servlet extends HttpServlet {

    /**
     * Processes requests for both HTTP <code>GET</code> and <code>POST</code>
     * methods.
     *
     * @param request servlet request
     * @param response servlet response
     * @throws ServletException if a servlet-specific error occurs
     * @throws IOException if an I/O error occurs
     */
    protected void processRequest(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
            throws ServletException, IOException {
        response.setContentType("text/html;charset=UTF-8");
        PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();
        try {
            HttpSession session = request.getSession(); 

            /* TODO output your page here. You may use following sample code. */
            out.println("<!DOCTYPE html>");
            out.println("<html>");
            out.println("<head>");
            out.println("<title>Servlet EX02W03</title>");            
            out.println("</head>");
            out.println("<body>");

            //create immutable object
            Integer add = 1;

            //create mutable object 
            Counter count = new Counter(add);

            //check to see if the session exists (if it is the users first time)
            if (session.getAttribute("timesLoggedIn") == null) {

               count.increment();               
               out.println("<h1>This is your first visit!</h1>");
               session.setAttribute("timesLoggedIn", count.getCounter());

            }else{

                count.increment();
                out.println("<h1>You have visited this page " + count.getCounter() + " times! </h1>");
                session.setAttribute("timesLoggedIn", count.getCounter());
            }


            out.println("</body>");
            out.println("</html>");


        } finally {
            out.close();
        }
    }

    // <editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc="HttpServlet methods. Click on the + sign on the left to edit the code.">
    /**
     * Handles the HTTP <code>GET</code> method.
     *
     * @param request servlet request
     * @param response servlet response
     * @throws ServletException if a servlet-specific error occurs
     * @throws IOException if an I/O error occurs
     */
    @Override
    protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
            throws ServletException, IOException {
        processRequest(request, response);
    }

    /**
     * Handles the HTTP <code>POST</code> method.
     *
     * @param request servlet request
     * @param response servlet response
     * @throws ServletException if a servlet-specific error occurs
     * @throws IOException if an I/O error occurs
     */
    @Override
    protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
            throws ServletException, IOException {
        processRequest(request, response);
    }

    /**
     * Returns a short description of the servlet.
     *
     * @return a String containing servlet description
     */
    @Override
    public String getServletInfo() {
        return "Short description";
    }// </editor-fold>

}
```

Counter Class:

```
/*
 * To change this license header, choose License Headers in Project Properties.
 * To change this template file, choose Tools | Templates
 * and open the template in the editor.
 */

package Question1;

/**
 *
 * @author Owner
 */
class Counter {

    private int count; 

    public Counter(int counts) {
        count = counts;
    }


    public int getCounter(){
        return count;    
    }

    public void increment(){
        count++;

    }




}
```

**FIXED - I fixed this problem with the placement of the two immutable/mutable objects, they are to go before the "protected void processrequest..."

Comment: I think you create the counter on each page load, so it should start new each time (i.e. whenever a request is send). Try calling `count.increment();` a few times after creating the counter to see if I'm right. I.e. if you call it 3 times you should always see "you visited 4 times".
To count the visits of each client you should save them somewhere on your server and load the corresponding count on each page request and increment it.
edit: it also increments once because you construct the counter with 1 and then increment it, so it get's 2 when you show the number.

Comment: @SebastianHöffner Where exactly then would I create a the counter object?

Comment: Just where you do it now, just read in the number of visits before (if the client is known) and put that number in the constructor.

Answer (score 2):

Create a Filter (this way you not copy and paste on each servlet) and then use a static (http://www.caveofprogramming.com/frontpage/articles/java/java-for-beginners-static-variables-what-are-they/) int.

```
public class urlFilter implements Filter {

@Override
public void init(FilterConfig config) throws ServletException {
}

@Override
public void doFilter(ServletRequest req, ServletResponse res, FilterChain chain) throws ServletException, IOException {

myStaticVariable ++;    
}

@Override
public void destroy() {
}
```

}

then on the web.xml

```
<filter>
    <filter-name>urlRewriteFilter</filter-name>
    <filter-class>com.example.UrlRewriteFilter</filter-class>
</filter>
<filter-mapping>
   <filter-name>urlFilter</filter-name>
   <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
</filter-mapping>
```

Comment: Thank you for your efforts. However I would like to use immutable and mutable objects so I have experience with them. Is there a way to still use them in my code?

Answer (score 0):

new Counter object is created when the page is reloaded/refreshed hence it is not getting incremented. Below method is just another way to achieve what you are trying.

```
        if (session.getAttribute("timesLoggedIn") == null) {

           out.println("<h1>This is your first visit!</h1>");
           session.setAttribute("timesLoggedIn", 1);

        }else{

            int i = Integer.parseInt(session.getAttribute("timesLoggedIn"));
            out.println("<h1>You have visited this page " + i + " times! </h1>");
            session.setAttribute("timesLoggedIn", i+1);
        }
```